# How to log to the console a list of a JavaScript object's keys

Tags: javascript

How do I `console.log` a list of the keys of an object (e.g. "`12342341`" in the code below)?

```
var data =
  {
    "12342341": {
      "City": "Montgomery",
      "State": "AL"
    },
    "23482342": {
      "City": "New York",
      "State": "NY"
    }
  }

console.log('City: ', data[12342341].City);
```

Comment: `console.log('City: ', data['12342341'].City);`

Comment: @Rayon That's logging the city, but it seems OP wants to list the array *names* (eg 12342341) , not their content.

Comment: @TylerRoper – The code OP has provided will return nothing...

Comment: I'm not refuting that, simply clarifying that OP's question was "How do I console.log a list of the array names (e.g. 12342341)?". Being that your comment included no context, it could be misconstrued as an answer to his question, though it is not.

Comment: Terminology note: the code shown is neither JSON nor an array. It's an object.

Comment: `Object.keys(data).map(k => data[k].City)` I downvote because I feel that there is nothing idiomatic. You just extract the data and print them. It is stupid to ask how to print the data when you are aware of the console.log. Similarly, there is nothing idiomatic about extracting a field called name`. Will you create another question to ask how to extract the states?

Comment: @LittleAlien - The OP is asking how to extract the names of properties, not how to use `console.log()`. They don't know how to extract "12342341" and "23482342" (they must not know about `Object.keys()`).

Comment: @LittleAlien – Well in that case, you may down-vote the question.. Why answer ?

Comment: @Rayon :  `data[12342341].City` would have the same effect... since property accessor convert it to string internally https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/8zn29amd/

Comment: @user3731460 - I have (again) removed the "json" tag from your question because there is no JSON in your question. JSON is a *string* format used for data interchange. What you have is simply an object.

Comment: @nnnnnn I have removed "JSON array" from the title, as there is no JSON in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)** methods to retrieve the property name array and **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method for generating `City` property value array from it.

```js
var data = {
  "12342341": {
    "City": "Montgomery",
    "State": "AL"
  },
  "23482342": {
    "City": "New York",
    "State": "NY"
  }
};

// get property name array
var arr = Object.keys(data);

// iterate over property name and
// generate `City` property value array
var names = arr.map(function(v) {
  return data[v].City
});

console.log(arr, names);
```

**FYI :** If you just want the property name array then avoid the **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** part.

Comment: No matter how valid your `Down-vote` is, do care to give a reason in comment-box @downvoter...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question asked to log the numbers. So `Object.keys(data)` is all they need; the `map()` is redundant (though still a useful example).

Comment: @nnnnnn : initial answer only contains the property names :) map is added just now

Comment: @LittleAlien  ___a list of the keys of an object (e.g. "12342341" in the code below)?___